# Загрузка видео и создание постера

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, ffmpeg

что будет лучше загружать видео создавать постер к нему в php через ffmpeg и сохранять его или лучше все это делать на js и отправлять его в php и там уже сохранять если не учитывать безопасность и если не сложно можно простыми понятными для новичка примерами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В принципе достаточно не сложно получить один кадр прямо на страничке, в сниппете ниже Вы можете выбрать видео с диска, проиграть его до нужного кадра, затем захватить этот кадр кнопкой pick, после чего появится канва, на которой этот кадр нарисован и можно сверху нарисовать линии. После всего этого нажав на кнопку download можно скачать получившуюся картинку.

```js
select.onchange = e => {
  if (!video.canPlayType(select.files[0].type)) 
    return
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(select.files[0]);
  hideShow([select], [video, pick]);
};

pick.onclick = e => {
  canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
  canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
  canvas.getContext ('2d').drawImage (video, 0, 0);
  hideShow([video, pick], [canvas, download]);
}

download.onclick = () => {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = 'frame.png';
  link.href = canvas.toDataURL()
  link.click();
}

function hideShow(hide, show) {
  show.forEach(el => el.style.display = 'block')
  hide.forEach(el => el.style.display = 'none')
}

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var pos = {};

document.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', setPosition);

function setPosition(e) {
  pos.x = e.layerX;
  pos.y = e.layerY;
}

function draw(e) {
  if (e.buttons !== 1) 
    return;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#c0392b';
  ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
  setPosition(e);
  ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y); 
  ctx.stroke(); 
}
```

```html
<input id="select" type="file" accept="video/*"/>
<button id="pick" style="display:none">pick frame</button>
<button id="download" style="display:none">download</button>
<video id="video" style="display:none" controls></video>
<canvas id="canvas" style="display:none"></canvas>
```

Comment: Дело в том что мне нужно скачивать картинку это даже не картинка, а постер к видео. Я имел в виду пользователь загружает видео на сайт, при загрузке создается постер к видео ссылку на постер храню в базе и т.д. и т.п. вот в чем вопрос

Comment: @Gradusnik ну это отличается от ответа только последней стадией, где я скачиваю картинку, Вам ее надо загрузить на сервер.

Comment: Там же в ручную надо кликать и воспроизводить видео а мне нужно, чтоб он брал автоматический кадр по середине без проигрывания видео

Comment: @Gradusnik а как я мог угадать это из вопроса?

Comment: Моя ошибка, айм сорри( и вопрос был что лучше делать все это через ffmep или на js

Comment: @Gradusnik видео на сервер закачивается только для этого? или видео и так и так на сервер закачивается?

Comment: Сайт на который можно будет загружать видео и потом смотреть, видео портал, видео сайт, что-то в этом роде

Comment: @Gradusnik тогда конечно лучше делать это на сервере

Comment: А лучше почему?

Comment: @Gradusnik чтобы ну раз Вы и так грузите видео на сервер, добавить одну команду к обработке не сложно, а если делать на клиенте придется дописать не мало кода

Answer (score 0):

Вариант в котором сразу на канве появляется средний кадр

```js
select.onchange = e => {
  if (!video.canPlayType(select.files[0].type)) 
    return
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(select.files[0]);
  chain(100, [
    e => video.currentTime = video.duration/2,
    e => canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height),
    e => canvas.toBlob(blob => fetch('/post/image', {method: 'POST', body: blob})
                                .then(resp => resp.json())
                                .then(res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res))))
  ]);
};

function chain(timeout, funcs) {
  funcs.length && setTimeout(e => {
    funcs.shift()(); 
    chain(timeout, funcs);
  }, timeout);
}
```

```html
<input id="select" type="file" accept="video/*"/><br>
<video id="video" style="display:none" controls></video>
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Просто копирую, вставляю и Uncaught ReferenceError: select is not defined это со мной что-то не так или у меня что-то не подключено?

Comment: `<input id="select" ` скрипт надо вставлять в конце `html`, либо в `onload`

Comment: а canvas может например, как в ВК с видео. Постер как бы есть но видео не запускалось?

Comment: ясно, лучше использовать это все на стороне сервера, чтобы видео каждый раз не грузилось у клиента, чтоб создать постер

Comment: @Gradusnik он может быть создан в момент выбора с диска, перед загрузкой видео на сервер и сохранен в паре с видео

Comment: Его(созданную картину) можно отправить как file на сервер? если да то как это сделать?

Comment: @Gradusnik я дополнил ответ

Comment: Я конечно прошу прощения за глупый вопрос но как можно отправить фото по методу POST? и в php ни в POST ни в FILES ничего нет, добавил отправку формы также ничего нет, или проще как его найти в php этот файл

Comment: @Gradusnik это уже вопрос про php, не подскажу почти не писал на нем