# Создание постера с помощью canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Как создать постер к видео с помощью canvas и js чтоб постеры к видео создавались при загрузке страницы с видео ну или создавались при загрузке видео на сервер пользователем потом оно выводилось можно простыми примерами без php

Comment: Вам же дали хороший [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1008998/256824), в котором даже кадр можно выбрать.

Comment: Там нужно сначала воспроизвести видео чтобы получить кадр а мне этого не надо

Comment: Вам дали основу, а как получить нужный вам кадр автоматом и выполнить загрузку видео и постера на сервер уже дело десятое.